# C# Login form - Setting Global Variables available throughout program

Tags: c#, sql, authentication

Ok, so my background is in VBA-Msaccess (SQL Server Backend). Have been developing for around 6 years. Our company has recently been hit massively by the limitations of MsAccess so have decided to start developing in C# and integrating into our existing back end.

I can quite easily solve this issue but I just want to make sure I am solving it in the most ideal way.

So I have a login form (Win forms) that is passing a username and password into a login class. The login class then compares the information against data in SQL server and returns a true or false value based on whether there is a matching record found. Within the class, I have then setup properties to contain information about the user ie their permission levels.

The issue I am having is, while this works fine because I am instantiating an object from login.cs these permission levels are then only contained within the created object and are not accessible after the login page. Presumably, I need to be storing this permission information in static or global variable but I just wish to know the most optimized and well-formed way of doing this!

C# Login Form

```
public partial class frmLogin : Form
{
    public frmLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = txtUsername.Text;
        string passWord = txtPassword.Text;

        Login login = new Login("","");

        string user = txtUsername.Text;
        string pass = txtPassword.Text;


        if (login.IsLoggedIn(user, pass))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(login.adminUser.ToString());
            frmMainMenu form = new frmMainMenu();
            this.Hide();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Log in failed please try again!");
        }


    }
}
```

Login.cs

```
public  class Login
{

    public  string UserName { get; set; }
    public  string PassWord { get; set; }
    private  bool aUser;
    private  bool tLeader;

    public  bool adminUser
    {
        get
            {
            return aUser;
            }
         set
            {
            aUser = value;
            }
    }

    public  bool teamLeader
    {
        get
        {
            return tLeader;
        }
        set
        {
            tLeader = value;
        }
    }

    public Login(string user, string pass)
    {
        this.UserName = user;
        this.PassWord = pass;
    }

    private void ClearText(string user, string pass)
    {
        user = string.Empty;
        pass = string.Empty;
    }

    public bool IsLoggedIn(string user, string pass)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter the user name!");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            ConnectionStrings connstring = new ConnectionStrings();
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connstring.connNameUser);
            sqlConn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT username, password, door_order_admin, super_user from dbo.[user] WHERE username = @user and password = @pass";

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);

            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt16(reader["door_order_admin"]) == 1)
                {
                    aUser = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    aUser = false;
                }

                if (Convert.ToInt16(reader["super_user"]) == 1)
                {
                    tLeader = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    tLeader = false;
                }


                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                ClearText(user, pass);
                return false;
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be massively appreciated. Like I said, I want to make sure I am starting out on the right foot as opposed to writing a bunch of code only to realize further down the line that I could have done it much better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe your question is better posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can try look into Session for storing data temporary since you only need to intialise it after login?

Comment: You should look for IPrincipal and IIdentity in the System.Security namespace. They can be used for role based access control. Typically, the principal object is assigned to your application domain (only once) on startup by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal()`. It can be accessed by `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` anywhere in your program.